# undelete all the files with testdisk

Tags: command-line, data-recovery, testdisk

My GF deleted a load of her photos, and Im trying to recover them with `testdisk`.
using the utility, I selected Advanced, and Undelete, but i dont see how to just choose all the deleted photos. Im following this guide: https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Undelete_files_from_NTFS_with_TestDisk

It appears like I have to select the files individually? how do i select all the deleted photos?

There is evidently many, deleted photos, and I am very drunk already.
simple solutions pls.

[image]

Comment: Use the `a` key, try that!

Comment: I tried the `a` command, and while it did highlight everything, the options to `c` continue or whatever would not recover more than on file at a time. I ended up retrieving 989 files manually, one at a time, which sucked.